Analog Textview.append("text")) on Jetpack Compose?
I want the text to be added to the previous one when the tracked value changes, rather than redrawn completely.
I looked through the methods in Basic Text and Text but didn't find anything.
Previously I could implement this using Textview.append("text"))

First, you should consider whether you actually need LiveData in your case.
It seems like you are coming from Android Views, but Compose follows a reactive approach, so you do barely need LiveData in Compose. Once you update the data, the UI will refresh to display the updated data by default. So in Compose, instead of modifying the View / Composable directly, you just update the data. See the last section in this post for alternatives to LiveData.
When you are using LiveData to handle the text, you should declare the LiveData in your ViewModel. This ViewModel would look as follows:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _myLive = MutableLiveData("")    // modify this from ViewModel
    val myLive: LiveData<String> = _myLive       // observe this in Composable

    fun appendText(appendValue: String) {
        _myLive.value += appendValue
    }
}

Then, in your Composable, observe it like this:
@Composable
fun MainComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val mytext: String by myViewModel.myLive.observeAsState()

    Text(text = mytext)
    Button(
        onClick = { myViewModel.appendText("ABC") }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Click to append ABC")
    }
}


Without LiveData. you could achieve the same thing as in above code using this simpler code:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var myText: String by mutableStateOf("")       // observe this in Composable

    fun appendText(appendValue: String) {
        myText += appendValue
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {

    Text(text = myViewModel.myText)
    Button(
        onClick = { myViewModel.appendText("ABC") }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Click to append ABC")
    }
}

Or, if you only need myText locally in a single Composable, do
@Composable
fun MainComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {

    var myText by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    Text(text = myText)
    Button(
        onClick = { myText += "ABC" }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Click to append ABC")
    }
}


You can do something like textview.append("text") in jetpack like below
@Composable
fun App() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Initial Text") }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
        Text(text)
        Button(onClick = { text += " Append text" }) {
            Text("Append Text")
        }
    }
}

Hope this helps

I listen to the text using "val mytext: String? by myLive.observeAsState()" . and when i use "onValueChange = {text += mytext}", I'm getting a lot of null values ​​in text even before the program starts
